# How to make callouts match the color of their target items?

Tags: labeling, visualization, charts, style, plot-themes

How to make callouts in a bubble chart in the same style as below? Specifically, I'd like to know how to make the callout stems match their target bubble colors (automatically).

[image]

What I've tried:

```
n=6;
lbls=ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{n, 10}];
BubbleChart[Callout@RandomReal[1,{n,1,3}],
     ChartLabels->Callout[lbls,LeaderSize->{Automatic,90\[Degree],Automatic},CalloutStyle->Automatic]]
```

An ideal solution would make recreate the stem's shape too (90 degrees with the little dot) and work for other charts/plot types, e.g. BubbleChart3D, BarChart, etc, e.g.

```
BarChart[<|"a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->5,"d"->3|>,
     ChartLabels->Callout[Automatic,Above,CalloutStyle->66],ChartStyle->66]
BubbleChart3D[RandomReal[1,{n,1,4}],ChartLabels->Callout[lbls]]
```

**Notes:**

- The above graphic comes from [this old blog post](https://www.reforge.com/brief/analyzing-the-power-of-two-sided-marketplaces#Ba7WJtL1PwUHkXtx6Nh7SQ) from Netflix

Answer (score 9):

```
n = 20;
SeedRandom[77];

lbls = ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{n, 10}];
data = RandomReal[1, {n, 3}];
```

#### BubbleChart

Use `Callout` as wrapper on input data:

```
bubblechart = BubbleChart[MapThread[
      Callout[Style[#, Directive[EdgeForm[]]], #2, Automatic, 
        Appearance -> "Leader", 
        LabelVisibility -> All,
        CalloutMarker -> 
           Arrowheads[{{0, 1}, {Automatic, 0,          
             Graphics[{ Opacity[.5], Disk[Offset[{-5, 0}, {0, 0}], Offset[5]]}]}}], 
        CalloutStyle ->
           {Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], #3], Opacity[0]}] &, 
    {data, Style[#, FontSize -> 14] & /@ lbls, ColorData[66] /@ Range[n]}], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ChartStyle -> 66, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5],
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
 postProcess = ReplaceAll[ {_Polygon -> {}, 
    Arrow[a_, ___] :> Arrow[a, {0, -.0075}], 
    Text[a_, Offset[o_, b_], c_] :> 
       Text[a /. Rule[FontSize, _] :> Rule[FontSize, Scaled[.025]], 
        Offset[o/3, b], (-Sign@o) /. {0, y : Except[0]} :> y {-1.2, 0.5}]}];

 postProcess @ bubblechart
```

[image]

```
Show[postProcess @ bubblechart /. 
   {Offset[5] -> Offset[3], Offset[{-5, 0}, p_] -> Offset[{-3, 0}, p]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Notes:** It is important (1) to use a large font size in printer points rather than in scaled size, and (2) to use a large image size in the original chart. Try using `FontSize -> Scaled[.02]` (instead of `FontSize -> 14`) and `ImageSize -> 300` (instead of `ImageSize -> 500`) in the code above to see the reason.

#### BarChart

```
data2 = data[[;; 10, 1]];
lbls2 = lbls[[;; 10]];

barchart = BarChart[
  MapThread[
    Callout[Style[#, Directive[EdgeForm[]]], #2, Automatic, 
        Appearance -> "Leader", 
        CalloutMarker -> 
           Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 0,                      
             Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Disk[Offset[{-5, 0}, {0, 0}], Offset[5]]}]}}], 
        LeaderSize -> {{Automatic, 90 Degree, 0}, {10, 0 Degree}}, 
        CalloutStyle -> 
           Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], #3]] &, 
    {data2, Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.02]] & /@ lbls2, ColorData[66] /@ Range[10]}],
  ChartStyle -> 66, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5],
  ImageSize -> 800, 
  BarSpacing -> - .1]
```

[image]

```
Show[ReplaceAll[{_Polygon -> {},
     Text[a_, Offset[o_, b_], c_] :> 
        Text[a, Offset[o/4, b], {-Sign[o[[1]]], 0}]}] @ barchart, 
    ImageSize -> 800, ImagePadding -> {{5, 50}, {5, 5}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[ReplaceAll[{_Polygon -> {},
      Text[a_, Offset[o_, b_], c_] :> 
       Text[a, Offset[{7, 10}, b], {-1, 1}, {0, 1}]}] @ barchart, 
     ImageSize -> 800, ImagePadding -> {{5, 5}, {5, 90}}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[MapThread[
   Callout[Style[#, Directive[EdgeForm[]]], #2, Automatic, 
      CalloutMarker -> 
          Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 0, 
            Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Disk[Offset[{-5, 0}, {0, 0}], Offset[5]]}]}}], 
      CalloutStyle -> Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[.5], #3]] &, 
   {data2, Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[.02]] & /@ lbls2, ColorData[66] /@ Range[10]}],
   ChartStyle -> 66, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5],
   ImageSize -> 700, 
   ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 100}}, 
   BarSpacing -> - .2] /. 
 {_Polygon -> {} , 
  Text[a_, Offset[o_, b_], c_] :> Text[a, Offset[{0, 25}, b], {-1, 0}, {0, 1}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For `BarChart` we can get the desired look using a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) since label positioning is much easier compared to `BubbleChart`:

```
ClearAll[CEF]
CEF[cedf_ : Automatic, o_ : 5] := 
  Module[{bb = 1.05 Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"][[2, 2]]},
  {Opacity[.5], Disk[Offset[{0, o}, {Mean@#[[1]], bb}], Offset[o]], 
   Text[Style[#3[[1]], FontOpacity -> 1, 14], Offset[{0, 3 o}, {Mean@#[[1]], bb}], 
      {-1, 0}, {0, 1}], 
   Thick, CapForm["Butt"], Line[{{Mean@#[[1]], #2}, {Mean@#[[1]], bb}}],
   (cedf /. Automatic -> ChartElementData["Rectangle"])[##]}] &
```

***Examples:***

```
n = 20;
SeedRandom[777];

lbls = ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{n, 10}];
data = RandomReal[1, n];
```

Attach labels to data as metadata:

```
labelrules = Thread[data -> lbls];


BarChart[labelrules,  
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
  ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5]],
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 10}, {20, 100}},
  BarSpacing -> {.1, 1},
  ChartElementFunction -> CEF[Automatic, 3]]
```

[image]

An example with multiple datasets:

```
labelrules2 = Partition[labelrules, 4];
grouplabels = Style["group " <> ToString @ #, 16] & /@ Range[5];

BarChart[labelrules2,  
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
  ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5]],
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 10}, {20, 100}},
  BarSpacing -> {.1, 1},
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[grouplabels, Axis], None},
  ChartElementFunction -> CEF[Automatic, 3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Automatic placement of labels to avoid overlaps is a difficult task. Instead we can interactively position the labels using a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html).

The following `ChartElementFunction` allows control of label positions using [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html)s. The position of the label for a bubble is restricted to stay outside the bounding rectangle of the bubble. The label of a bubble is connected to the nearest of the four poles of the bubble. The first argument specifies the radius (in printer points) of the disk at the tip of the connector line. The second argument gives the style of the line and the third argument specifies the edge style of the main bubble and its connected disk.

A few requirements:

1. We need to  use `BubbleChart` with the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` and  wrap `BubbleChart` with [`Deploy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Deploy.html) to get the `Dynamic` elements work properly.
2. The labels should be attached to input data as metadata using the form `{data1 ->label1, data2 -> label2 ...}`.

```
ClearAll[labeledBubbleWithConnector]
labeledBubbleWithConnector[o_: 5, connectorstyle_: Thick, edgeform_: None] := 
 With[{bubble = First @ Cases[ChartElementData["Bubble"]@##, _Disk, All], 
    center = Mean /@ #, 
    box = TransformedRegion[Rectangle @@ Transpose @ #, 
      ScalingTransform[{1.25, 1.25}, Mean /@ #]], 
    color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}, 
   DynamicModule[{locator = center + 1.2 {bubble[[2, 1]], 0}, 
     label = #3[[1]], value = #2[[-1]], 
     anchors = center + # & /@ 
       Join[Thread[{{1, -1} bubble[[2, 1]], 0}], 
        Thread[{0, {1, -1} bubble[[2, 2]]}]]}, 
    {EdgeForm[edgeform /. Automatic -> Darker[color]], 
     Tooltip[bubble, value],
     Locator[Dynamic[locator, 
        (locator = If[RegionMember[box]@#, 
           RegionNearest[RegionBoundary@box]@#, #]) &], None], 
     Dynamic @ Module[{anchor1 = First @ Nearest[anchors, locator, 1], 
        middle, off = Sign[locator[[1]] - center[[1]]]}, 
       middle = Sequence @@ 
         If[Sign[anchor1[[2]] - center[[2]]] ==  0,
           {{(anchor1[[1]] + locator[[1]])/2, anchor1[[2]]}, 
            {(anchor1[[1]] + locator[[1]])/2, locator[[2]]}},
           {{anchor1[[1]], locator[[2]]}}]; 
       {FontOpacity -> 1, Text[label, Offset[2 o { off, 0}, locator], -{off, 0}], 
        Disk[locator, Offset[o]] ,
        CapForm["Butt"], connectorstyle, 
        Line[{anchor1, middle, Offset[-o {off, 0}, locator]}]}]}]] &
```

***Examples:***

```
dt = Thread[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}} ->
   (Style[#, 16, Black] & /@ {"aaplvhpmyk", "stuzprmmfp", "abgpfhxuop"})]; 

Deploy @ 
  BubbleChart[{dt}, 
   BubbleScale -> "Diameter", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{.5, 1.5}, {.5, 1.5}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, 
   ImagePadding -> {{83, 83}, {20, 20}}, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5]], 
   ChartStyle -> {None, "Rainbow"}, 
   ChartElementFunction -> labeledBubbleWithConnector[3]]
```

[image]

```
n = 20;
SeedRandom[77];

lbls = ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{n, 10}];
data = RandomReal[1, {n, 3}];

BubbleChart[{Thread[data -> (Style[#, 14, Black] & /@ lbls)]}, 
 BubbleScale -> "Diameter", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ImagePadding -> {{83, 83}, {20, 20}}, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[.75]], 
 ChartStyle -> {None, "Rainbow"}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> labeledBubbleWithConnector[3], 
 DisplayFunction -> Deploy]
```

[image]